# Write mysql database from Excel 2011 on mac

Tags: mysql, excel, macos

I am able to connect to an existing database from excel with Microsoft Query. The database is empty. I want to export datas from my xslx to the mysql databse. How to do it?

Comment: look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html

Comment: Thanks  but it is MySql for Excel which is not available for Mac as I know.

Comment: You can start by installing the MySQL Connector for Mac, downloadable from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ Also remember that SO is not a code writing service. Please try a google search for available solutions and post what you have tried so far. Regards,

Comment: Also you can import directly in MySQL a .csv. With your xslx save as .csv and import into your database.